req.file is undefined even after uploading the image file. Using Next js and multer for file upload
I am creating a form using next js (both backend and frontend) with many fields out of which one field is image upload (same is the name of the field in mongoose schema). First I upload the image on my local server using multer and get the local file path for the image. Then I use this local file path to upload the image on cloudinary platform. It returns me an url for the image which I store in my database.
The problem is that even after I am sending the image from the form, still I am not getting anything in req.file. It is coming undefined.
Can anyone please suggest me changes.
/client/middleware/multer.js
import multer from "multer";
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const uploadDir = './public/assets/upload';

// Ensure the upload directory exists
if (!fs.existsSync(uploadDir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir, { recursive: true });
}

// Configure multer storage
console.log("welcome from multer")//these console logs are there to check whether storage function is getting invoked or not
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log("Multer: Saving to local directory");
    cb(null, uploadDir); // Save the file in the 'uploads' directory
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); // Unique file name
  }
});
console.log("bye from multer")
export const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

/client/app/api/users/profile/route.js
import { createRouter } from 'next-connect';
import { connect } from '@dbConfig/dbConfig';
import User from '@models/UserModel';
import { upload } from '@middleware/multer';
import { uploadOnCloudinary } from '@helpers/cloudinary';

// Connect to your database
connect();

// Create a router with next-connect
const handler = createRouter();

// Middleware to handle file uploads using multer
handler.use(upload.single('image')); // 'image' corresponds to the form-data key

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false // Disable automatic body parsing, as we're using multer
    }
};

// POST request handler
export async function POST(req, res) {
    try {
        // Ensure the file exists
        if (!req.file) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
        }

        // Access the file path (local path where the image was saved)
        const profilePhotoLocalPath = req.file.path;

        // Access other fields from req.body (multer parses text fields automatically)
        const { id, username, highlights, designation, institute, bio } = req.body;

        // Log form data for debugging
        console.log("Form Data Received: ", {
            id, username, highlights, designation, institute, bio
        });

        // Validate if 'id' exists
        if (!id) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "User ID is required" });
        }

        // Fetch the user and update their profile details
        const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: id },
            { username, highlights, designation, institute, bio },
            { new: true }
        );

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "User doesn't exist" });
        }

        // Upload profile photo to Cloudinary
        const avatar = await uploadOnCloudinary(profilePhotoLocalPath);

        if (avatar?.url) {
            user.profilePhoto = avatar.url;
            await user.save();
        }

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Profile details updated successfully",
            success: true,
            user
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in the API route:", error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
}

I initially tried to call upload function (multer middleware) using promise resolve method without using next handler and then now I am using handler but still same result. I expect multer to return me local file path name which I would pass to cloudinary to upload it on their server.

Are you sure you are passing the file correctly? usually, when req.file is undefined this is the issue

@Cake I guess so because I am currently testing this backend using postman where I am just uploading it in a multiform data
